# Can Realm be used on a Web-App on PC as well?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am currently working on an app with React Native and we have quite some problems deciding which Database to use.

Realm is one of the options which came into the closer circle, but we are now wondering if it is possible to access a Realm database from both a device and a Desktop/Web Applikation?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://realm.io/blog/introducing-realm-react-native/ that should help you. Short answer: yes, Realm can be used on a Web-App as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will take a look right now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is: 'yes' it can be used.
Please look at comments for more detail.